# How to pass multiple parameters into a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I am working on that is returning an invalid return when I try to pass parameters to it compared to when I run it with hard-coded values.

Procedure with hard coded values:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase 
        WHERE OrgID = '2781823' 
            AND PurchaseMonth>'2015-03-01'
    ) as DistinctCount;
END
```

When run, this returns: 16 which is correct.

Procedure with two input parameters:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase 
        WHERE OrgID = orgid 
            AND PurchaseMonth>sincedate
    ) as DistinctCount;
END
```

The input parameters are defined as:

IN `userid` integer,IN `orgid` integer,IN `sincedate` date

When run, this returns: 334 which is not correct.

I am new to stored procedures and would appreciate any assistance offered regarding what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to resolve?

Thanks...

Comment: Please edit your question and show your procedure as well as how you're calling it.

Comment: Hi, right not I am just trying to run the stored procedure in Navicat. When I get it working I am calling the procedure from an application developed in AwareIM and so the calling procedure is likely not relevant?

Comment: The reason I wanted to see it was to see what you're passing in as orgid and sincedate.  Are you providing the correct values in Navicat?

Comment: I believe that I am. When I run the procedure in Navicat it prompts me for the two parameters, I enter 2781823,2014-01-01

Comment: 2014-01-01 is not the same as 2015-03-01.  Why would you expect the same number of results?

Comment: The strange this is that if I add the input parameter "IN `orgid` integer", even if I still leave the query alone with hard coded values in the where portion of the select statement, it returns a count of all 31 instead of 16. If I remove the where portion of the query entirely and remove the parameter, I get 344.

Comment: Sorry, I must have changed the date at one point but it gives the same results with the correct date

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Your question indicates that you're using three parameters (userid, orgid, sincedate) but you're only passing in two (userid) isn't used.  Leave the procedure as shown in your question and pass in 2781823 and 2015-03-01.  What do you get?

Comment: Originally my procedure was as follows:

Comment: BEGIN
DECLARE countpurchases INTEGER;

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM ( SELECT * FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase WHERE OrgID = orgid AND PurchaseMonth>sincedate) as DistinctCount;
UPDATE sandbox_user SET KPI_Option_DistinctSkuPurchases_Recent = countpurchases WHERE ID = userid;

END

I stripped out the second line in order to troubleshoot and just get the count working. If I run the procedure that uses the two input parameters in the where portion, and add 2781823,2014-03-01 as the inputs, I get a count of 344 which is the full dataset instead of the expected count of 16.

Comment: I added an answer.  Please take a look and see if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

add "@" before your parameters:

```
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) 
    FROM ( 
       SELECT * 
       FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase 
       WHERE OrgID = @orgid 
           AND PurchaseMonth>@sincedate
    ) as DistinctCount; 
END
```

a fast turtorial will be: [Write-a-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-To-Write-a-Stored-Procedure-in-SQL)
(see how to use parameters at the end of this page...)

Comment: Hi, Thanks but now I just get a result of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try using input parameters that are not the same name as your columns.
Change:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase 
        WHERE OrgID = orgid 
            AND PurchaseMonth>sincedate
    ) as DistinctCount;
END
```

To:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase 
        WHERE OrgID = p_orgid 
            AND PurchaseMonth > p_sincedate
    ) as DistinctCount;
END
```

And pass IN p_orgid integer,IN p_sincedate date

The parser may be seeing `WHERE OrgID = orgid` and that evaluates to true for every record since it evaluates as an identity (comparing against itself).

Comment: Hi, A different result but still not the same as hard coded values:

BEGIN


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM ( SELECT * FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase WHERE OrgID='2781823' AND PurchaseMonth>'2015-03-01') as DistinctCount;


END

Returns: 16

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM ( SELECT * FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase WHERE OrgID = p_orgid AND PurchaseMonth> p_purchasemonth) as DistinctCount;

END

with input parameters:

IN `p_orgid` integer,IN `p_purchasemonth` date

Values: 2781823,2015-03-01

Returns: 49

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you putting single quotes around your date, '2015-03-01'?

Comment: I wasn't but I have now and it solved it! I guess it was treating it as a calculation. Mark, thank you very much for your help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Param Name and field name must be different!

`BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM sandbox_inventoryitempurchase 
        WHERE OrgID = p_orgid 
            AND PurchaseMonth > p_sincedate
    ) as DistinctCount;
END`